# How to convert "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z" to "April 1, 2018" using javascript/ES6/ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I get date from API response in following format

"2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"

I want to display it as "April 1, 2018" on my page. Can someone help me in converting it

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried moment.js moment("2018-04-01T00:00:00Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD")  and got "2018-04-01". I need to format it to April 1, 2018. I want to know if we can format it in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
moment("2018-04-01T00:00:00Z").format("MMMM D, YYYY")
```